# Cipher initialization error when running test

Tags: java, encryption

I wrote a utility program to do encryption and decryption using AES algorithm. Regular program works fine but when I run test with same method I am getting Cipher initialization error on `doFinal` method.

I did some research and some suggest to put `init` and `doFinal` in a synchronized block. I did that and still getting same exception.

I also updated `US_export_policy.jar` and `local_policy.jar` in `jre7/lib/security` folder as suggested by some forum. Still getting same issue.

What could be wrong in the code?

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class CipherUtil {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CipherUtil.class);
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F";
    private Cipher cipher;
    private SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;

    private static CipherUtil cipherUtil;

    private CipherUtil() {
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            log.error(ex);
        }
        byte[] key = null;
        try {
            key = Hex.decodeHex(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray());
        } catch (DecoderException ex) {
            log.error(ex);
        }
        secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    }

    public static synchronized CipherUtil getCipherUtilObject() {
        if (cipherUtil == null) {
            cipherUtil = new CipherUtil();
        }
        return cipherUtil;
    }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }

    public String encrypt(String plainText) {
        if (plainText == null)
            return null;
        String encryptedText = null;
        byte[] encrypted = null;

        synchronized (cipher) {
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        synchronized (cipher) {
            try {
                encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                encryptedText = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted));
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException
                    | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return encryptedText;
    }

    public synchronized String decrypt(String encryptedText) {
        if (encryptedText == null)
            return null;
        byte[] toDecrypt = null;
        byte[] original = null;
        String decryptedText = null;

        synchronized (cipher) {
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        toDecrypt = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText);
        synchronized (cipher) {
            try {
                original = cipher.doFinal(toDecrypt);
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        try {
            decryptedText = new String(original, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return decryptedText;
    }
}
```

and the test class:

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CipherTest {
    CipherUtil cipherUtil;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        cipherUtil = CipherUtil.getCipherUtilObject();
    }

    @Test
    public void testEncryptDecrypt() {
        String plainText = "Secret Message";
        String encryptedText = cipherUtil.encrypt(plainText);
        assertThat(encryptedText, not(equalTo(plainText)));
        String decryptedText = cipherUtil.decrypt(encryptedText);
        assertThat(decryptedText, is(equalTo(plainText)));
        assertThat(encryptedText, not(equalTo(decryptedText)));
    }
}
```

and finally this is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCipherState(Cipher.java:1672)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2079)
    at com.testapp.util.CipherUtil.encrypt(CipherUtil.java:67)
    at com.testapp.util.CipherTest.testEncryptDecrypt(CipherTest.java:23)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to synchronize Cipher objects? Your synchronization code is not correct. But it would slow down multi-threaded applications like there is no tomorrow if it would work. Note that your code is using ECB mode of operation, and is therefore not cryptographically safe either. I would advice against creating such generic wrappers in the first place.

Comment: No ... initially Cipher object wasn't in synchronized box and I was getting same Exception. As I mentioned I added those synchronization as per suggestion in other questions.

Comment: You have a strong tendency not to accept answers and abandon questions. I think that is rude to the extreme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code ran fine on my machine. Note that your `encrypt` method is not synchronized, so running this in a threaded environment will make it fail. In general you should have one `Cipher` instance per thread. `Cipher` contains state *between* method calls, so just synchronizing access to the method calls themselves will fail from time to time.